# Is it true that $\binom{a}{x}\binom{b}{y}=\binom{a+b}{x+y} -\binom{a}{x+y}-\binom{b}{x+y}$ when $x+y\leq a, b$?

Tags: combinatorics

I was solving a question and came across this product of combinations:

> $$\binom{a}{x}\binom{b}{y} \tag{1}$$

So, I figured out it should be

> $$\binom{a}{x}\binom{b}{y}=\binom{a+b}{x+y} -\binom{a}{x+y}-\binom{b}{x+y} \tag{2}$$

Obviously for $x+y \leq a,b $

Is it right? My line of thinking is breaking apart a group into $a$ and $b$ and then choosing $x$ and $y$ from each of them respectively. The other side is choosing $x+y$ from $a+b$ and subtracting all the choices made solely from $a$ and solely from $b$.

I just want to know if it is right and if there's a name for this relation.

If not, where's the flaw?

Answer (score 2):

It is not true.

The correct way to pick a fixed number of elements from either of two sets is illustrated by the following example, where three elements are picked from sets of sizes four and three,
$$
\binom{4+3}{3}=\binom{4}{0}\binom{3}{3}+\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{2}+\binom{4}{2}\binom{3}{1}+\binom{4}{3}\binom{3}{0}.
$$
You should be able to see that $\binom{a}{x}\binom{b}{y}$, $\binom{a}{0}\binom{b}{x+y}$, and $\binom{a}{x+y}\binom{b}{0}$ are only a few among many possibilities for picking $x+y$ elements from sets of sizes $a$ and $b$ in general, and that all possible ways of splitting the $x+y$ elements between the two sets must be included.